# Compilation in Vue.js stops at 66% or 67%

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image: Screenshot of console stuck on 66%]

I have a project in Vue.js version `2.6.10`, but, when compiling it with `yarn serve`, the compilation stops at 67% and doesn't advance.

Comment: try the steps, it may fix the problem: 1. **delete** the folder named `node_modules`; 2. run `yarn install`; 3. run `yarn serve`

Comment: This can happen if you have an error on your .vue files, check your project files and make sure if there are no errors.